# Outlook Add-In not working on mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've been working on creating custom Add-In for Outlook. I've created project using Yeoman, the project is in TypeScript with ReactJS. I've validated my manifest with `office-addin-manifest` - the result was positive. I host my React application on IIS, it is visible to public (redirect page opens in browser without log in).
After installing manifest on Outlook desktop application, it is working on desktop application and on browser on desktop but not on mobile application.
The redirect address which is in manifest opens on mobile phone on browser, but my Add-In displays blank page.

Here, there is a snippet from my manifest containing mobile part:

```
<MobileFormFactor>
        <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
          <Group id="mobileGroupID">
            <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
            <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="mobileButton1">
              <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.16x16" scale="1"/>
                <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.16x16" scale="2"/>
                <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.16x16" scale="3"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" scale="1"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" scale="2"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" scale="3"/>
                <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.80x80" scale="1" />
                <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.80x80" scale="2" />
                <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.80x80" scale="3" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </ExtensionPoint>
        <!-- possibly more ExtensionPoint elements -->
      </MobileFormFactor>
```

I've been using Fiddler Everywhere with proxy redirection in order to monitor request from Add-In on mobile Outlook, but it was displaying only domain address of redirect, no whole address.

Did someone have a similar issue? Or maybe someone has any idea what may cause blank page on my mobile application?

Comment: Fiddler could be the reason for blank page load. Outlook playstore app does not accept fiddler certificate as a trusted certificate. Can you try without fiddler and check?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - From the beginning I had a blank page, that is why I used Fiddler to monitor the request - whether is send and where is send.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT you were right, blank page was caused by Fiddler. I had an opportunity of deploying my site on server which hosts publicly available site and after this my web add-in was working fine on mobile application. Is there any way to test my web add-in during development -> after changing something I deploy web add-in on sever which is visible only with appropriate entry in hosts file.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Durng development I encourntered another problem with displaying new window with page from different domain than the one from my web add-in. I was using dialogAPI as it is advised in documentation, but on mobile version of Outlook new window displays a blank page. I added my new domain in manifest section. I've tried using `window.open(...)` but it did not succeed. Is there any known approach to open new window with page from new domain ?

Comment: Regarding your question on displaying a new window, Dialog API should be used. Please check if there are any errors in callback method. Documentation  on possible errors is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-handle-errors-events..
Regarding, your question on testing Add-in during development, Could you please provide more clarity on the requirement?